# Wiremock Date format

Tags: java, wiremock, handlebars.java

I want to generate date in the format `2019-03-28T15:30:59+12:00` using wiremock.

I tried:

```
"currentDateTime": "{{now timezone='Australia/Sydney' format='yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ'}}"
```

but, I get exception:

> wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline:
>   found: ''yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ'', expected: 'no viable alternative at
>   input ''yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ'''

I have also tried escaping both the quotes around `T`, but it does not work.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The quotes at your format string are unbalanced due to the quoted T in the middle: `format='yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`'. I guess you have to escape this somehow.

Comment: @RajKishan How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @ShahbazAhmad I did not find a direct solution. So I used a hack instead. What I did is, put a placeholder in place of the date like `"currentDateTime":"currentTimePlaceholder"`. Then in a custom transformer (extend `ResponseTransformer`), replace that string with the desired value which is easy to do.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else comes across this post in the future, the simplest (but hacky) solution that I used is to format the parts before and after the 'T' separately like so:

```
"currentDateTime": "{{now timezone='Australia/Sydney' format='yyyy-MM-dd'}}T{{now timezone='Australia/Sydney' format='HH:mm:ssZ'}}"
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple workaround:

1. Declare a variable (`myformat` in the example)

   `{{#assign 'myformat'}}yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ{{/assign}}`
2. Use it in the stub/mock

   `{{now format=myformat}}`

A sample templated response is -

```
{
    "time": "{{#assign 'myformat'}}yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ{{/assign}}{{now format=myformat}}"
}
```

---

References

- How to use custom variables in Handlebars for WireMock
  https://wiremock.org/studio/docs/response-templating/misc-helpers/#assignment

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :)!
How can i declare handlebar variables inside the wiremock json document?

Answer (score 3):

Try using following block of code. Working fine for me and probably the best way.
`format='yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX'`

Answer (score 3):

If you need to include the date in the ISO 8601 format, you can omit the `format` option:

```
{{now timezone='Australia/Sydney'}}
```

It will produce the following result: `2021-06-09T05:45:53+10:00`. If you omit the timezone and just use `{{now}}` - it will produce a date in UTC: `2021-06-08T19:48:27Z`.

For reference, you can check the [`RenderableDate`](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/extension/responsetemplating/helpers/RenderableDate.java) class in wiremock

Comment: This is the correct answer; it needs to be placed higher up the list/accepted!

Answer (score 0):

```
"body": "{\"datetime\": \"{{now format='yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss'}}\"}"
```

Comment: Please add a short description and explanation to your code instead of just posting the code snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simpler version that works for formatting in Wiremock

```
"{{now format='yyyy-MM-dd'}}T{{now format='HH:mm:ss.SSS'}}Z"
```