# ISO date format in Wiremock

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm trying to return stubbed date in Wiremock.
The expected date is today in ISO format `yyyy-MM-dd`.
I cannot make it work. Here's the error:

```
.pointInTime [equalToDateTime] now +0 seconds| 2022-04-13}
```

Here's my relevant part of the mapping:

```
{
  "matchesJsonPath": {
    "expression": "$.pointInTime",
    "equalToDateTime": "now",
    "actualFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd"
  }
```

As far I can say, Wiremock has problems with dealing with dates only without time part.

**EDIT**
I tried to use answers from post given by @Sambit without no luck.

```
{
   "matchesJsonPath":{
      "expression":"$.pointInTime",
      "equalToDateTime":"{{now timezone='Europe/Warsaw'}}"
   }
}
```

Here's the `now...` part is tried as literal:

`$.pointInTime [equalToDateTime] {{now timezone='Europe/Warsaw'}}>  but was 2022-04-13`

Comment: May be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602585/wiremock-date-format

Comment: If using @Sambit's answer, you'll need to specify a format in your `equalToDateTime` => `"equalToDateTime": "{{now timezone='Europe/Warsaw' format='yyyy-MM-dd'}}"`, otherwise it will include hours/minutes/seconds. You may also want to try triple brackets instead of double... I've found the behavior to be frustratingly inconsistent (tbf, I haven't dug into why and when to use three vs. two => `{{{}}}` vs `{{}}`)

Comment: @agoff Thanks for this. I tried your solution but it failed to work. I also tried triple brackets. Each time Wiremock interprets what is inside `{}` as string literl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to truncate the expected value (the one represented by `now`) to the first hour of the day so that you're matching date only with date only:

```json
{
  "matchesJsonPath": {
      "expression": "$.pointInTime",
      "equalToDateTime": "now",
      "truncateExpected": "first hour of day"
  }
}
```